# Is it a correct way to clear the exim mail queue?

Tags: linux, email, exim, cpanel

I use the following command to delete the exim mail queues

```
exiqgrep -i | xargs exim -Mrm
```

or

```
# following commands seems to work faster compared to the above.
exim -bpru | awk {'print $3'} | xargs exim -Mrm
```

But the above commands do not work when the mail queue size is more than 100,000. It get stuck. So, I am using the following script which works fine regardless of the number of mails in the queue.

My question is, will it delete correctly ?

```
/etc/init.d/exim stop;
sleep 10;
killall -9 exim eximd
sleep 5;

#clean out the mail queue
find /var/spool/exim -mindepth 2 -type f -exec rm -rfv {} \;

#clean out the mail db files
find /var/spool/exim/db -type f -exec rm -rvf {} \;

/etc/init.d/exim restart
```

Comment: Have you tried the `--max-args` or `--max-lines` (`-L`) options for `xargs`?

Answer (score 4):

I believe you are looking for this...

```
service exim stop
rm -fvr /var/spool/exim/input
service exim restart
```

However a slightly more sane method is to remove the messages on a per user basis...

```
egrep -Rl "((`pwd | cut -d / -f3`|$(grep `pwd | cut -d / -f3` /etc/userdomains | cut -d : -f1 | tr '\n' '|' | sed 's/|$//g'))|/home/`pwd | cut -d / -f3`)|X-Failed-Recipients" /var/spool/exim/input --include='*-H' | awk -F "/" '{gsub("-[A-Z]$","");print$NF}' | xargs exim -Mrm
```

Answer (score 2):

I have had success with the following, even when there are millions of emails in queue.

`for i in $(exim -bp | awk '{print $3}'); do exim -Mrm $i; done`

Comment: Note that the question contains an explicit question, "My question is, will it delete correctly ?", about a piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

In addition, to delete the emails of a specific user:

```
grep -lr 'user@domain.com' /var/spool/exim/input/ | \
    sed -e 's/^.*\/\([a-zA-Z0-9-]*\)-[DH]$/\1/g' | \
    xargs exim -Mrm

exim -bp | \
    grep "user_email-account" | \
    awk '{print $3}' | \
    xargs exim -Mrm
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove all messages from the queue, enter:

```
# exim -bp | awk '/^ *[0-9]+[mhd]/{print "exim -Mrm " $3}' | bash
```

Comment: This is worse performance than the version in the question.